# Fallo en mi codigo c++ de numeros romanos a arabigos

Tags: c++

quiero convertir de numeros romanos a arabigos en c++ e implementando el siguiente codigo al interpretar el numero XI me sale 13 en lugar de 11. Alguien podria darme una pista de donde esta el fallo?

El problema dice asi:

> Diseñar un programa C++ utilizando subprogramas que lea desde el dispositivo de entrada estándar
> una serie de caracteres que representan un número romano, lo convierta en arábigo, y lo escriba en
> la pantalla. Por ejemplo, si se lee desde el teclado XIV debe salir en la pantalla 14. Para ello tener
> en cuenta lo siguiente:
>
> Sea un número romano con dos símbolos ab
>
> Si a >= b entonces se suma el valor de b al valor de a. Ejemplo: XI
> (10 + 1 = 11) Si a < b entonces se resta el valor de a al valor de b.
> Ejemplo: IX (10 - 1 = 9)
>
> Utilizar la siguiente tabla de conversión entre símbolos romanos y
> cantidades.
>
> I = 1
>
> V = 5
>
> X = 10
>
> L = 50
>
> C = 100
>
> D = 500
>
> M = 1000

gracias.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string romano;
int conversion(string &numero);
int cantidades (char &n);

int main(){
    romano.clear();
    int resultado;
    cout << "Introduzca numero romano: ";
    getline(cin,romano);

    resultado= conversion(romano);

    cout << resultado<<endl;

}

int conversion(string &numero){

    int tam = numero.size();
    int suma=0,a,b;

    for (int i=0;i<(tam);i++){
       
       a = cantidades (numero[i]);
       b = cantidades (numero[i+1]);
        if(a>=b){
            suma=suma+(a+b);
        }else{
            suma=abs(suma+(a-b));
        }
    }
return suma;
}

int cantidades (char &n){
int j;
if (n=='I'){
     j=1;
}
if (n=='V'){
     j=5;
}
if (n=='X'){
     j=10;
}
if (n=='L'){
     j=50;
}
if( n=='C'){
     j=100;
}
if (n=='D'){
     j=500;
}
if (n=='M'){
     j=1000;
}
return j;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 for (int i=0;i<(tam);i++){
   a = cantidades (numero[i]);
   b = cantidades (numero[i+1]);
```

`tam`será 2, así que el bucle iterará para `i = 0` y para `i = 1`. Pero en la segunda iteración, harás

b =  cantidades(numero[2]);

que es un elemento fuera del array (*undefined behavior*).

Además, en la primera iteración ya has sumado la primera y la segunda letras. Si tenemos una cadena más larga, por ejemplo `XII`, en la primera iteración sumarás `XI` (11) pero luego en la segunda sumarás `II` (2), con lo que tendrás 13.

En general, como forma de programación defensiva, estaría bien que `cantidades` lanzara una excepción (o al menos imprimiera un mensaje de error) si le llega un valor que no es ninguno de los esperados, si alguien te pone `Z`, entonces `cantidades` te devolverá un valor cualquiera.